# How to select elements within boundary?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out a way to select elements that are overlapped (and contained, completely covered up) within an absolutely positioned div.

I basically need to select elements within a certain pixel boundary. How can this be done using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the basic idea:

```
var left = 100,
    top = 200,
    right = 300,
    bottom = 500;

$('#main-div').children().filter(){
    var $this = $(this),
        offset = $this.offset(),
        rightEdge = $this.width() + offset.left,
        bottomEdge = $this.height() + offset.top;

    if (offset.top > top && offset.left > left && right > rightEdge && bottom > bottomEdge) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Change the coordinates at the top to whatever you need.

Comment: if `#main-div` is my absolutely positioned div, I know the x and y offsets, but the children will not be on the `#main-div`, it will be on the `body` tag. So do I just traverse the body until one of the elements matches? (I wonder what kind of performance that will have)

Comment: @Andrew - If that's the way it is, then you'll have to traverse all the elements on the page. Are you sure you're approaching this problem the right way? There might be something else you could do instead (not that I know, just saying).

Comment: if that's the only way, then I guess that's how I'll do it. there may be a better solution, but this will do for now. thanks!

Comment: @Andrew I believe that the values at the top is your absolute div with `#main-div` being a container of your "underneath" elements. Note that it is only traversing a single level (via `children()`).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your html is something like:

```
<div id="thediv"></div>
<div id="one">one</div><br />
<div id="two">two</div><br />
<div id="three">three</div><br />
```

You could have this jQuery:

```
$('div:not(#thediv)').filter(function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var left = offset.top;
    var top = offset.top;
    var right = left + $(this).width();
    var bottom = top + $(this).height();

    var offset2 = $('#thediv').offset();
    var left2 = offset2.top;
    var top2 = offset2.top;
    var right2 = left2 + $('#thediv').width();
    var bottom2 = top2 + $('#thediv').height();

    if (
        (
            (left < left2 && right > left2)
            || (left > left2 && right < right2)
            || (left < right2 && right > right2)
        )
        &&
        (
            (top < top2 && bottom > top2)
            || (top > top2 && bottom < bottom2)
            || (top < bottom2 && bottom > bottom2)
        )
        )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}).css('background-color', 'red');
```

And the divs that overlap with the main div would turn red. You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/u9RRD/2/).

The idea is to get the `offset()`, `width()` and `height()` of the elements, and see if they overlap. The code is probably not very efficient, I wrote it like this to make it clear.

Comment: this is a little bit different than I originally wanted, but still useful. Your answer selects the elements if one of the corners overlaps, rather than being completely enclosed in the bounds. I could see myself using this one instead. So you get a +1. =]